# How concatenate a TCHAR array with a string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tchar

i have the following code:

```
enter code here
TCHAR szSystemDirectory[MAX_PATH] ;
GetSystemDirectory(szSystemDirectory, MAX_PATH) ;
_stprintf(szSystemDirectory, _T("%s"), L"\\");

AfxMessageBox(szSystemDirectory);
```

and wants concatenate two slashes to ***szSystemDirectory*** variable, but final result always like this:

**\**

How solve?

thank you by any help or suggestion.

Comment: Why not just use a string class?

Comment: [You've run up against escape characters.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) TLDR; '\' has special meaning. "\\" is one slash. If you want two, you have to use 4: "\\\\"

Comment: TCHAR is not a real type; it's a #define that gets set to either CHAR or WCHAR depending on whether the UNICODE flag is set. There's no real reason to use it anymore, and in fact your code wouldn't work if the UNICODE flag wasn't set since you're using the `_T()` and `L` macros interchangeably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the "two slashes" thing is not just something you see in the debugger (since it would show a single slash as an escaped one) but - the **biggest** issue you have is that your are overwriting the contents of `szSystemDirectory` with the `_stprintf` call. I guess what you wanted was to print the `\` character at the end of the path. Try

```
TCHAR szSystemDirectory[MAX_PATH + 2]; // 1 for null terminator, 1 for the slash
UINT nCharactersWritten = GetSystemDirectory(szSystemDirectory, MAX_PATH);
szSystemDirectory[nCharactersWritten] = _T('\\');
szSystemDirectory[nCharactersWritten + 1] = _T('\0');
```

or for two slashes:

```
TCHAR szSystemDirectory[MAX_PATH + 3]; // 1 for null terminator, 2 for the slashes
UINT nCharactersWritten = GetSystemDirectory(szSystemDirectory, MAX_PATH);
szSystemDirectory[nCharactersWritten] = _T('\\');
szSystemDirectory[nCharactersWritten + 1] = _T('\\');
szSystemDirectory[nCharactersWritten + 2] = _T('\0');
```

`_stprint_f` has been declared deprecated in Visual Studio 2015, so if you want to use the printing functions you can try:

```
TCHAR szSystemDirectory[MAX_PATH + 2]; // 1 for null terminator, 1 for the slash
UINT nCharactersWritten = GetSystemDirectory(szSystemDirectory, MAX_PATH);
_stprintf_s(szSystemDirectory + nCharactersWritten, MAX_PATH + 2 - nCharactersWritten, _T("%s"), _T("\\"));
```

or for two slashes

```
TCHAR szSystemDirectory[MAX_PATH + 3]; // 1 for null terminator, 2 for the slashes
UINT nCharactersWritten = GetSystemDirectory(szSystemDirectory, MAX_PATH);
_stprintf_s(szSystemDirectory + nCharactersWritten, MAX_PATH + 3 - nCharactersWritten, _T("%s"), _T("\\\\"));
```

Answer (score 1):

\ is the escape character. e.g. "\n" codes a newline. What that means is that \ always indicates that the next character is to be treated as a special character. So when you want to tell the compiler that you want a *literal* \ character you need to escape it the same way:

```
\\ codes a single \

\\\\ codes double slashes
```